# Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, compiler-errors

I have error running a quiz game. Something like this (when open gameactivity). My application stop and I ge Binary XML file error on line #0. It`s kinda weird, becouse I didnt see problem like this with line 0, so I need your help, everyone. Thanks!

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: sarveshchavan777.triviaquiz, PID: 2901
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{sarveshchavan777.triviaquiz/sarveshchavan777.triviaquiz.MainGameActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:650)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:793)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:827)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:869)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:827)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:288)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143)
       at sarveshchavan777.triviaquiz.MainGameActivity.onCreate(MainGameActivity.java:36)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6980)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert value at index 1 to color: type=0x5
       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:473)
       at info.hoang8f.widget.FButton.parseAttrs(FButton.java:116)
       at info.hoang8f.widget.FButton.<init>(FButton.java:52)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:650) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:793) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:827) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:869) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:827) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377) 
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:288) 
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143) 
       at sarveshchavan777.triviaquiz.MainGameActivity.onCreate(MainGameActivity.java:36) 
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6980) 
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Where MainGameActivity.java:36 is: `setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_main);`

**activity_game_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fbutton="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="sarveshchavan777.triviaquiz.MainGameActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/lightGreen"
        android:minHeight="?actionBarSize">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="0dp">



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/triviaQuizText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/timeText"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/coinText" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/timeText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="@string/time"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"></View>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/triviaQuestion"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/question"
            android:textColor="@color/grey"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/resultText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/green"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonA"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:onClick="buttonA"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/grey"
            fbutton:buttonColor="@color/white"
            fbutton:cornerRadius="10dp"
            fbutton:shadowColor="@color/grey" />

        <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonB"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:onClick="buttonB"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/grey"
            fbutton:buttonColor="@color/white"
            fbutton:cornerRadius="10dp"
            fbutton:shadowColor="@color/grey" />


        <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonC"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:onClick="buttonC"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/grey"
            fbutton:buttonColor="@color/white"
            fbutton:cornerRadius="10dp"
            fbutton:shadowColor="@color/grey" />

        <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonD"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:onClick="buttonD"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/grey"
            fbutton:buttonColor="@color/white"
            fbutton:cornerRadius="10dp"
            fbutton:shadowColor="@color/grey" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: here: info.hoang8f.widget.FButton.parseAttrs(FButton.java:116)

Comment: delete your app build folder , make project and run it again.

Comment: @pskink So this is library error?

Comment: @HemantParmar didnt work

Comment: i have no idea if FButton.java is your class or it belongs to any library - you know it better

Comment: I think the problem is with library itself, try to use color instead of reference, let me know if it works

Comment: if we use app level attribute in xml than we used  xmlns:fbutton="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" and those class must be in our project. hope you get my point.

Comment: try to delete  xmlns:fbutton="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" and do auto import.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem comes with the library itself, If you check [`attrs.xml`](https://github.com/hoang8f/android-flat-button/blob/master/library/src/main/res/values/attrs.xml):

```
<attr name="buttonColor" format="color" />
```

As you can see the `buttonColor` only accepts color value, **NOT** color reference, and the view is trying to convert reference value you pass in xml to color and it throws an exception, So you can only use color for this attribute ( *like this: #000000*) Or fork the project and modify [`attrs.xml`](https://github.com/hoang8f/android-flat-button/blob/master/library/src/main/res/values/attrs.xml) like this:

```
<attr name="buttonColor" format="color|reference" />
```

Comment: `fbutton:shadowColor` has to be changed too

Comment: Sure! it's weird that no reference is used there

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove cornerRadius property it's causes the problem may be it's library issues

```
fbutton:cornerRadius="10dp"
```

Remove it's all buttons and it's work well