# How do I resolve this InflateException - after clicking a button?

Tags: android

This is the error that occurs when I click a button:

```
09-15 01:09:08.934 32386-32386/com.example.ajalandoni.chemistryworld E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.ajalandoni.chemistryworld, PID: 32386
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ajalandoni.chemistryworld/sarveshchavan777.triviaquiz.MainGameActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #105: Binary XML file line #105: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2781)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2859)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1592)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6518)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #105: Binary XML file line #105: Error inflating class <unknown>
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #105: Error inflating class <unknown>
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at sarveshchavan777.triviaquiz.MainGameActivity.onCreate(MainGameActivity.java:36)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7013)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7004)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2734)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2859)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1592)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6518)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert value at index 1 to color: type=0x5
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:473)
    at info.hoang8f.widget.FButton.parseAttrs(FButton.java:116)
    at info.hoang8f.widget.FButton.<init>(FButton.java:52)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
    at sarveshchavan777.triviaquiz.MainGameActivity.onCreate(MainGameActivity.java:36) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7013) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7004) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2734) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2859) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1592) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6518) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

This my **activity_game_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fbutton="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="sarveshchavan777.triviaquiz.MainGameActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/lightGreen"
        android:minHeight="?actionBarSize">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="0dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/coinImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/coin" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/coinText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text=""
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/coinImage"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/coinImage" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/triviaQuizText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/timeText"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/coinText"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/timeText"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/coinText" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/timeText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="@string/time"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"></View>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/triviaQuestion"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/question"
            android:textColor="@color/grey"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/resultText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/green"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonA"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:onClick="buttonA"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/grey"
            fbutton:buttonColor="@color/white"
            fbutton:cornerRadius="10dp"
            fbutton:shadowColor="@color/grey" />

        <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonB"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:onClick="buttonB"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/grey"
            fbutton:buttonColor="@color/white"
            fbutton:cornerRadius="10dp"
            fbutton:shadowColor="@color/grey" />


        <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonC"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:onClick="buttonC"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/grey"
            fbutton:buttonColor="@color/white"
            fbutton:cornerRadius="10dp"
            fbutton:shadowColor="@color/grey" />

        <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonD"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:onClick="buttonD"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/grey"
            fbutton:buttonColor="@color/white"
            fbutton:cornerRadius="10dp"
            fbutton:shadowColor="@color/grey" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

- What could be the possible cause of this problem?
- I already tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47221195/binary-xml-file-line-0-error-inflating-class-unknown/47221608), but this doesn't work for me.

Comment: are you sure about that class and package name? `info.hoang8f.widget.FButton`. Can you check FButton package name?

Comment: @wendell which library version you are using?

Comment: Does you define onClick of your button?

Comment: @iravul I add this project as a library to my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your dependency with this

```
compile 'com.github.jd-alexander:android-flat-button:v1.1'
```

use this library it will fix your problem. The library you are using has some issue check [this](https://github.com/jd-alexander/android-flat-button) library.

Also add `maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }` in build.gradle **(Project Level)** in repositories block your code will look like this :

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Comment: This gave me an error of 

Failed to resolve: com.github.jd-alexander:android-flat-button:v1.1
Show in File
Show in Project Structure dialog

Comment: @wendell_t i have edited my answer please check and let me know if you face any problem

Comment: Thank you so much. This fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think the problem is with the android gradle plugin version. Try changing it to 2.3.3 in File -> Project Structure -> Project.

Comment: Changing the plugin version , doesn't work for me. But thanks btw.